# What is the best solution for the 'Students and Lockers' problem?

Tags: performance

I thought that it would be fun to present some classic CS problems and let people show their algorithm optimization skills. The hope is that we get to see some clever techniques to solve abstract problems that we may be able to implement in practice.

Ideally solutions would be presented in pseudo code with a big O classification. Proof of that classification is gravy. On to the problem:

There are N closed lockers and N students present. The first student opens each locker. The second student opens or closes every second locker. This continues where the nth student opens and closes every nth locker. After N students what lockers are open? How many lockers are open?

Comment: No. this is purely an exercise for fun. I'm sure this has been given as homework many times though.

Comment: I would like to know if anyone considers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269202/rosetta-stone-students-and-lockers a dup of this one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Students will only flip the state of those lockers that their number is a divisor of (student 2 flips the even lockers, student 3 flips the lockers divisible by 3, so on and so forth...).  So, the only lockers that will remain open after N rounds are those that have an odd number of divisors (because they start closed, an odd number of flips will leave it open).  The only numbers that have an odd number of divisors are perfect squares, so all of the perfect-square-numbered lockers will be left open.  So after N rounds, the number of lockers left open will be the square root (floored) of N.

This solution would be O(sqrt(N)) to know **exactly which** lockers are open, but O(1) if you only need to know **how many** lockers are open.

Comment: A lot of the time algorithms involving sequences with repeating patterns can be condensed down to a simple formula.  This was a good one though, it takes a little knowledge of number theory.  I like that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer without using Arrays (or objects etc) and not using the square root method.

====

## include

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int studentTotal , lockerTotal,  visit, totalOpened = 0, totalClosed = 0;

cout << "Enter number of students" << endl;
cin >> studentTotal;

lockerTotal = studentTotal;

```
for (int locker = 1; locker <= lockerTotal;  locker++ ){ // locker loop
    cout << "\n\n\nLocker no." << locker << endl;
    cout << " is visited by student(s) ";
    visit = 0;
    for (int student = 1 ; student <= studentTotal; student++) { // student loop

    if( locker % student == 0) {
            cout << student << ", ";
            visit++;}

    }//end of locker loop

    cout << "\nTotal number of visits: " << visit;
    if (visit % 2 == 0){
        cout << " the locker will stay closed.";
        totalClosed++;}
    else { cout << " the locker will be opened.";
        totalOpened++;}

} //end of student loop

if (lockerTotal == totalOpened + totalClosed) {
    cout << "\n\n\nOf total lockers (" << lockerTotal << "), " << totalOpened << " will be left open." << "(" << totalClosed << ") " << "will be closed." << endl;
    }else cout << "Error!!";



return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In O(log N) based on the interval of open lockers following the series 1+2k:

```
delta=1

for(index=1;index < N;index+=delta) {
   print open locker = index;
   delta+=2;
   opencount++;
};
```

Comment: It can't be O(log N), because there are √N open lockers and you need to print all of them. 

Also, sum of the first k odd numbers is k^2, so your code is just a complicated way of printing all the square numbers less than N. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would see how quickly I could come up with a solution in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub lockers{
  my($number_of_lockers) = @_;

  my $largest_sqrt = sqrt $number_of_lockers;

  my @list;

  for( my $index = 1; $index <= $largest_sqrt; ++$index ){
    push @list, $index**2;
  }

  return @list;
}

say for lockers 100;
```

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

Or, if you don't want to calculate the Square root, of the number of lockers.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub lockers{
  my($number_of_lockers) = @_;

  my @list;

  for(
    my($index,$sqr) = (1,1);
    $sqr <= $number_of_lockers;
    $sqr = (++$index)**2
  ){
    push @list, $sqr;
  }

  return @list;
}

say for lockers 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this as a hw assignment.

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE / 2; i++){
   for(int k = i; k < SIZE; k = k+i+1){
      if(lockers[k] == false)
        lockers[k] = true;
      else
        lockers[k] = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could optimise this by removing the `if` statements and replacing them with a single `lockers[k] = !lockers[k]`, As that is just inverting

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with the least code.

Author:Moazzam Ali

```
   public class CH3 {
```

`    public    static    void    main   (String   []   args) {
        boolean [] lockers= new boolean[100];

```
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        lockers[i]=true;
                          }

    for(int s=2;s<100;s++){
        for(int y=s; y<100;y=y+s){
            if(lockers[y]==true){
                lockers[y]=false;
                               }
            else{
                lockers[y]=true;
                }
                              }
                          }
System.out.println("open lockers are:");
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
if(lockers[i]==true){


System.out.print(i+"  ");
}
}
```

}}

Answer (score -1):

*Below is the java code using brute force method. It checks for each and every student, and what he does to every particular locker. 
There is better approach. Assume there are 100 students and 100 lockers.
Then Sixth locker will be touched by Student 1, Student 2 and Student 3. 
1X1, 2X3, 3X2. But only lockers with squares will have even number of students touching them.*

**Thus better to solve is finding out the Squares present between the numbers.**

***Java Code:***

```
  int l, s;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the number of lockers");
  l = in .nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter the number of students");
  s = in .nextInt();
  if (l

   boolean lockers[] = new boolean[l + 1]; 
   boolean students[] = new boolean[s + 1]; lockers[0] = true; students[0] = true;
   for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
lockers[i] = false;
   }

   for (int j = 1; j <= s; j++) {
for (int h = 1; h <= l; h++) {
 if (h % j == 0) {
  if (lockers[h] == true) lockers[h] = false;
  else lockers[h] = true;
 }

}
 }
   System.out.println("the lockers which are open are ");
   for (int k = 1; k <= l; k++) {
       if (lockers[k] == true) {
       System.out.print(" " + k);
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is just unformatted code without any explanation about how it works.